# Laravel query join as extra json

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to build one page app with Vue.JS and Laravel.
I want to show latest topics.

TopicController:

```
public function index()
{
    return response()->json( Topic::allTopics() );
}
```

Topic:

```
public static function allTopics()
{
    return Topic::select('id', 'title', 'author_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();
}
```

By this I got something like this:

```
[
    {"id":322,"title":"mytitle..","author_id":"authorname"},
    {"id":321,"title":"anothertitle..","author_id":"authorname.."}
]
```

How can I make author as extra json? Like

```
id: N,
title: "title",
author_id: 5
    author_name: "Name",
    author_avatar: "default.png"
```

etc.. I know that I can join users table, but this don't be an extra json? How can I build my custom json? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = Topic::select('id', 'title', 'author.author_name as author_id')
->join("author",'author.id','=','topic.author_id')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
$array = [];
foreach($result as $data){
  $array[] = [
     'id'=> $data->id,
     'key_name2'=> $data->title,
    ......

  ];
}

return response()->json($array);
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 Topic::select('id', 'title', 'author.author_name as author_id')
->join("author",'author.id','=','topic.author_id')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: `I know that I can join users table, but this don't be an extra json` :)